# How to render embedded Elm module synchronously?

Tags: elm

I am trying to embed "HelloWorld" module into existing HTML page. 
I found that module is rendered asynchronously (i don't get rendered element 
immediately after calling "embed").

I want to use Elm in an existing project and rewrite some parts of JavaScript
in Elm. But asynchronous rendering makes things difficult.

Is there a way to render it synchronously?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var appContainer = document.createElement('div');
    Elm.HelloWorld.embed(appContainer);
    console.log('Html: ' + appContainer.innerHTML); // Will print an empty string
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Html: ' + appContainer.innerHTML); // Will print "Hello, World!"
    }, 0);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloWorld.elm

```
module HelloWorld exposing (main)

import Html exposing (text)

main =
  text "Hello, World!"
```

**UPD:** Removed redundant code.

Comment: You have wrapped your initialization code in to `$(function () {...})`, which is a shorthand for [$(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). Why do you need jQuery anyway?

Comment: No, there is not really a way. I should probably add it to the FAQ, as it comes up quite often on the slack channel.

Comment: I have removed some redundant code including jQuery.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, and the ugly workaround was a horrible `setTimeout()`. I'm curious to see if someone can answer this one.

Comment: I would be nice to have `.embed()` returning a *Promise*, so that one could have the guarantee of the HTML rendered on the page.

Comment: hey @Eugene, any chances that my answer was useful? :)

Comment: Sure, @pietro909 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, Elm doesn't expose this kind of hook.
You have basically two different approaches, one based on *events* and the other based on *timing* (the `setTimeout()` method you are already using).

The event-driven approach involves the [MutationObserver Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Creating a new `MutationObserver`, you can observe the HTML Node onto which you run the Elm module: this way, you have a hook on the DOM update.

A naive check would be checking against the children's list of the `appContainer`:

```
<body>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var appContainer = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var mo = new MutationObserver(function(mutationRecords, instance) {
        for (var i = 0; i < mutationRecords.length; i += 1) {
            if (mutationRecords[i].addedNodes.length > 0) {
                // a trivial check
                console.log('Html: ' + appContainer.innerHTML);
                // stop observing, if not needed anymore
                mo.disconnect();
            }
        }
    });
    mo.observe(appContainer, { childList: true });
    Elm.HelloWorld.embed(appContainer);
</script>
</body>
```

Note that the above code is assuming that your *HelloWorld* module is adding children to the `appContainer`, so you should modify it conveniently:

```
module HelloWorld exposing (main)

import Html exposing (p, text)

main =
  p [] [ text "Hello, World!" ]
```